# trying to iterate data sets

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm new to javascript, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to loop through some code so that it will basically create an array that I can then pass on to my plot variable.

I'm not really sure where to start. Right now I have a chunk of code that takes my first dataset (dataOne) and formats it so that it can go into my plot variable. I basically need to do that three more times for the other data sets - hoping to include the example.getDataSets function to loop through somehow.

Is there a good way to do this?

Here is my code:

script.js

```
var example = {};

example.data = {
    dataOne: {data: [{"date":1333238400000,"data":23},{"date":1333324800000,"data":37},{"date":1333411200000,"data":49},{"date":1333497600000,"data":54},{"date":1333584000000,"data":30},{"date":1333670400000,"data":19},{"date":1333756800000,"data":15},{"date":1333843200000,"data":19},{"date":1333929600000,"data":145}],
    dataTwo: {data: [{"date":1335830400000,"data":63},{"date":1335916800000,"data":77},{"date":1336003200000,"data":66}],
    dataThree: {data: [{"date":1341100800000,"data":24},{"date":1341187200000,"data":50},{"date":1341273600000,"data":43},{"date":1341360000000,"data":39},{"date":1341446400000,"data":56},{"date":1341532800000,"data":66}],
    dataFour: {data: [{"date":1333238400000,"data":71},{"date":1333324800000,"data":46},{"date":1333411200000,"data":66},{"date":1333497600000,"data":73},{"date":1333584000000,"data":105},{"date":1333670400000,"data":84}]}
}

example.getDataSets = function(){
    return ['dataOne', 'dataTwo', 'dataThree', 'dataFour']
}

example.getSeries = function(month){
    return example.data[month]
}

example.processData = function(data){
    var newData = []
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        newData.push([data[i].date, data[i].data])
    };
    return newData;
}
```

My script in the HTML page:

```
$.getScript("script.js")
    .done(function() {

    var b = example.getSeries('dataOne');
    var d = example.processData(b.data);
    // first correct the timestamps - they are recorded as the daily
    // midnights in UTC+0100, but Flot always displays dates in UTC
    // so we have to add one hour to hit the midnights in the plot
    for (var i = 0; i < d.length; ++i)
      d[i][0] += 60 * 60 * 1000;

    var plot = $.plot($("#placeholder"), [d] , options);
```

Any suggestions are much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing the string literal `'b'` to `example.processData` not the *object* stored in the variable `b`. Its should be

```
var d = example.processData(b);
```

Also `example.getSeries` returns an object not an array. The array is in the `data` property of the object.

Also your data has syntax errors in it, missing `]}` at the end of the arrays in the first 3 objects.

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you know of a way that I can return the value of var d to the console? The example.processData is supposed to format the data a bit, and I need a way to make sure it's doing just that.

Comment: @Shipoopi I missed a `}` after the `]`, see updated answer. The array you want to manipulate is `b.data` so pass that to `example.processData`. `example.processData(b.data)`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var d = example.processData(b);
```

as

```
console.log('b')
```

won't log your `data` (in the `b` *variable*) as well, but the string :-)